# Are there any ways to get timestamp of document when created

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

When I created the messaging app, I forgot to add timestamp to the document. Is there a way to get the timestamp when the firestore document is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documents don't have any sort of metadata like this.  After you create the document, if you didn't originally add a creation timestamp to it, you won't be able to find it after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do :

```js
// add timestamp field when objective is created. 
exports.objectiveCreationDate = functions.firestore.document('objectives/{documentUid}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  // New document Created : add field with date
  db.doc(`objectives/${snap.id}`).update({
    creationDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  }, {merge: true});
});
```