# Getting timestamp/creation date from Firebase doc, where it is not saved manually?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to get Timestamp or creation date from firestore doc? No matter how hacky the solution is, anything is viable. I believe firestore has to store some kind of timestamp to every object it saves? If so, is there any way to get to that value? Previously in beta v1, they had this create_time field, which is apparently now removed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a bit old --but I think that the answer is a lie.  There is a created at timestamp.  If you look in the chrome devtools from the firestore console and go through the networking data to find where your browser reads the collection data there are additional fields on the document:

createdTime and updatedTime

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to get the creation timestamp from metadata of a Firestore document through the API. If you want such a value, you'll have to store it yourself.

See:

- [Is there a Firestore Timestamp in metadata for Document Creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59784116/is-there-a-firestore-timestamp-in-metadata-for-document-creation)
- [Add timestamp in Firestore documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846914/add-timestamp-in-firestore-documents)
- [Are there any ways to get timestamp of document when created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760493/are-there-any-ways-to-get-timestamp-of-document-when-created/57760608#57760608)
- [Firestore createId() ids not in chronological order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740788/firestore-createid-ids-not-in-chronological-order/52741265#52741265)